# AJAX .done() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't know where the problem is but found out that, if I change this line `data: form_data` to `data: form_data;` it doesn't return Ajax, but PHP function works.

> Default ajax, with line : `data : form_data` --> breaks page and php function won't work

[image]

> Adding ";" after that line `data : form_data;` --> Nothing displays, but PHP function works and Inserts "reply" in database

[image]

> Should look call PHP function and display alert dialog like here:

[image]

Reply Form:

```
<!-- REPLY MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade reply_comment_<?php echo $comment['id'];?>" id="reply_comment_<?php echo $comment['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <b><center><div class="modal-header">Reply Comment</div></center></b>
            <form id="replyForm_<?php echo $comment['id'];?>" class="horiziontal-form" action="../Pages/fun_post.php?action=replyCommentForm" method="post">
                <center><textarea name="reply" style="width:80%; height:200px; margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px; resize:vertical;" placeholder="Write your comment!"></textarea></center>
                <input type="hidden" name="addedby" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $myRow['id']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $comment['id']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $comment['post_id']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" style="float:right; margin-right:90px;" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Reply" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END OF REPLY MODAL -->
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#reply_comment_<?php echo $comment['id'];?>").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
        var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

        $.ajax({
            url : post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data : form_data
        }).done(function(response){ //
            $('#reply_comment_<?php echo $comment['id'];?>').modal('hide');
            document.getElementById('result-box').innerHTML += response;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

> WORKING EXAMPLE "REPORT POST FORM" USING SAME CODING

```
<!-- REPORT MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade report_post_<?php echo $post['id'];?>" id="report_post_<?php echo $post['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <b><center><div class="modal-header">Report Post</div></center></b>
            <form id="reportForm_<?php echo $post['id'];?>" class="horiziontal-form" action="../Pages/fun.php?action=reportPostForm" method="post">
                <center><textarea name="report" style="width:80%; height:200px; margin-top:20px; resize:vertical;" placeholder="Please describe your Report!"></textarea></center>
                <input type="hidden" name="addedby" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $myRow['id']; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="image_id" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" />
                <div class="modal-footer"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" value="Report" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- END OF REPORT MODAL -->


<script>
$(function(){

    $("#reportForm_<?php echo $post['id'];?>").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
        var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

        $.ajax({
            url : post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data : form_data
        }).done(function(response){ //
            $('#report_post_<?php echo $post['id'];?>').modal('hide');
            document.getElementById('result-box').innerHTML += response;
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `Adding ";" after that line data : form_data; --> Nothing displays` That's because adding the semi-colon there is a syntax error

Comment: If you put `;` after `data : form_data` you just get an error so the form submitting without the ajax, so it not count.

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya that's logically identical to what OP has now

Comment: Can you see the request in the `network` tab in DevTools? In other words, is the ajax request itself have been called or not?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I don't understand where problem is, because I use this code in "report form" too. And it all works.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors as @MoshFeu suggested?

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes, it requests.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't get any error in console.

Comment: In which case are you certain that your JS code is being executed at all? You should be seeing the AJAX request in the console.

Comment: Please reserve the use of blockquote formatting (`>`) for quotations. Do not use it to "highlight" sections. You don't need formatting there at all; this should be set in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're using the wrong selector for the form submit event handler. You're using:

```
$("#reply_comment_<?php echo $comment['id'];?>").submit(function(event){
    // ...
});
```

however `reply_comment_<?php echo $comment['id'];?>` is the ID for the modal (i.e. a `div` element). According to the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/submit/):

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to <form> elements.

The ID of your form is `replyForm_<?php echo $comment['id'];?>` so you should be using that instead:

```
$("#replyForm_<?php echo $comment['id'];?>").submit(function(event){
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. As I thought.. Mistake in my own coding. Simple bug, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @Crelix no problem :)